# Looking for a "fake approximation of identity"

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, convolution

I have read that a sufficient condition for a family of *approximations of the identity* $K_{\epsilon}={\epsilon}^{-n}K(x/{\epsilon})$, with K integrable and $\int K =1$ for wich the convolution converges a.e. pointwise to f,

$K_{\epsilon}\ast f(x)  \xrightarrow[\varepsilon \to 0]{} f(x)$  $\quad$ a. e. x,

is that

$\ell(x)=sup\{K(y):|y|\geq|x|\}$ , the *minimal non decreasing radial majorant* of K, must be integrable.

But this tell us that maybe the merely integrability of K is not a sufficient condition for the convergence. In fact, it's actually not, but I don't know how to find a counterexample! Please can somebody help me?